# Cannot get gdb working for Go 1.3 program

Tags: go, gdb

```
(gdb) info goroutines
Python Exception <class 'gdb.error'> 
Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a (null).:
Error occurred in Python command: 
Attempt to extract a component of a value that is not a (null).
```

**Version**:

```
GDB:    7.7.1  
Python: 3.4.1  
OS:     CentOS 6.5 x86_64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://golang.org/doc/gdb:

> **GDB does not understand Go programs well**. The stack management,
>   threading, and runtime contain aspects that differ enough from the
>   execution model GDB expects that they can confuse the debugger, even
>   when the program is compiled with gccgo. As a consequence, although
>   GDB can be useful in some situations, it is not a reliable debugger
>   for Go programs, particularly heavily concurrent ones. Moreover, it is
>   not a priority for the Go project to address these issues, which are
>   difficult. In short, the instructions below should be taken only as a
>   guide to how to use GDB when it works, not as a guarantee of success.

Also check [issue 7796](https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=7796&q=gdb&colspec=ID%20Status%20Stars%20Release%20Owner%20Repo%20Summary)

There's http://ernestmicklei.com/2012/12/14/hopwatch-a-debugging-tool-for-go/, which isn't like gdb, you have to add breakpoints yourself in the code.